# How to fix "Execution Timeout Expired." error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a query which works absolutely fine when run by SQL Server Management Studio

```
select *
from (
    select rtrim(Emp.s_filterh) res
    from Emp, Dept
    where Dept.r_label = 'xxx' and Emp.s_filtery = 1 and Emp.s_r_id = Dept.r_id 
    order by 1 desc offset 0 rows
) as r
```

but throws:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

error when run via application

This is my piece of code for executing SQL commands

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dr;
SqlConnection oc = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
command.CommandText = "select * from (select rtrim(Emp.s_filterh) res from Emp, Dept where Dept.r_label = 'xxx' and Emp.s_filtery = 1 and Emp.s_r_id = Dept.r_id order by 1 desc offset 0 rows ) as r";
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rlabel1", label);
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

There are many questions on this error but none seems to help my scenario.

Comment: What are you using parameter `rlabel1` for?

Comment: Read all those questions again. You have to find **why** the query took so long it timed out, not hide the problem by increasing the timeout. What you posted isn't the real query anyway - nobody uses `Empt` and `Dept` tables even for examples for almost 30 years, and most people avoid using the 1990's style JOIN. Sooner or later someone else is going to tell you to use `INNER JOIN` instead. Finally, using a subquery is pointless in this case - you're returning whatever the inner query produced, so what's the point?

Comment: In the *real* table, the JOIN or filter fields may have no indexes, resulting in a full table scan that takes Shared locks over the entire table. If some other query, eg an UPDATE or  INSERT modifies a row, it will take an Exclusive query that blocks Shared queries. Without indexes, your query will have to scan the entire table and *wait* for any modifications to complete, even if they don't affect the filtered rows.

Comment: `order by 1 desc offset 0 rows` what's the point? Ordering by position is another *very* bad idea. But `OFFSET 0 ROWS` is again pointless. If you wanted to get the first 10 rows you'd use either `TOP 10` or `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: Post the real query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for pointing out sub query point, I understood that subquery is not needed. I've posted the real query,  I also tried to use Inner query but seems like there is some syntax error so I'm trying to figure out the same. Thanks your points helped me in the right direction.

`select rtrim(Emp.s_filterh) res from  Prod.dbo.Emp  s, Prod.dbo.Dept  r
Inner join  Prod.dbo.Emp  on  Emp.s_r_id = r.r_id 
 where r.r_label = 'xxx' and s.s_filtery = 1 `

Comment: Read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). I don't see the `@rlabel1` parameter referenced in the query but [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/`) may be the cause of poor performance if it is.

Comment: And yet you are STILL using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). We now see that you use 3-part names (according to your comment where that information is buried and difficult to see) for your tables - another bad practice. Your connection should determine the database to use for your tables. I surely hope you do not write/test code using a production database.